# permission issue in nfs (ubuntu server) on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, permissions, nfs

I've created nfs-server in ubuntu 14.4 and create share on nfs as below :

```
$ /etc/exports
/myshare        *(rw,fsid=0,insecure,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash)
```

On ubuntu, 1000 id is for admin user and group.

Now Issue is that, If I create file on ubuntu server and open which on windows 7 then it's open as readonly !!

But If I create file from windows 7 then able to change it on ubuntu because in server I've set a  anonuid & anongid, After it's file open as readonly on windows 7 .

In short, How can create public share which can access windows to ubuntu and visevarsa.

Comment: What version of NFS are you using?

Comment: @EricRenouf i'm using nfs4 ,

Answer (score 0):

I made update in windows 7, by regedit:
 I put, AnonymousGid=1000 and AnonymousUid=1000 in register:
computer->HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->MICROSOFT->ClientNFS->CurrentVersion-Default

After that i include NFS client by 
Turn Windows features on or off and selected:
Service NFS 
 - Administrative Tools
 - Client for NFS

Good lock